# Centering text issue

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I used `\begin{center}` to align both of these lines in the center but it looks like this. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: that is two centred lines, what output did you want?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill% only demo

\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{l}
     E: Test text.\\
     F: Line 2 of test text.
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\hrule` is easier than `\noindent\hrulefill`, right? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shot in the dark answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
\pbox{\linewidth}{E: Test text.\\F: Line 2 of test text.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

using `\shortstack` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill% only demo

\begin{center}
  \shortstack[l]{E: Test text.\\F: Line 2 of test text.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]